# Do JWT refresh tokens have security benefits?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, token, refresh-token

I understand that having refresh tokens to generate access tokens makes your servers more scalable, since you can have a dedicated server just taking the refresh token and provide an access token.

But I'm wondering if the concept of a refresh token also provides security benefits?

In the end it doesn't matter, if either an unlimited refresh token is leaked or if you just have an unlimited access token that is leaked. In the end you have to invalidate one token, no matter which case. Am I right with that or am I missing something?

Comment: No it offers no security, its purely to get a new token when the old one expires. You should prevent it being leaked if it is then you have XSS issues, JWT are just tokens nothing more, you need to add layers to protect them like you would with session cookies, like not using local storage, using SSL and storing in http only secure cookies etc